# Powershell Remoting C# invoke-expression

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-remoting

As a result of [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472221/how-to-find-ip-for-interfaceindex-in-wmi) approach not working, I am trying a very convoluted way of getting complete route information on a remote machine.  I am trying to connect to a remote powershell runspace and execute the route.exe command line tool that way and return the information.

Essentially I am applying the solution found [**here**](http://scorpiotek.com/blog/?p=770) except I am trying to run the command: Invoke-Expression "c:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe print"
instead of "get-process"

When I use "get-process" it works.  When I try Invoke-Expression I get an exception telling me that this command-let cannot be found.  When I run the exact same command on the machine locally, it works and the routing information is displayed.  So I know it's not a syntax problem or a typo in the path.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so as soon as I posted this I had a brilliant, but obvious, idea. Technically the "Invoke-Expression" is the 'command' and the "c:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe print" is an argument of the command. So you need to add this to the code that I linked to above:

```
powershell.AddCommand(scriptText); 
powershell.AddArgument(args);
```

Where scriptText is the "Invoke-Expression" and args is "c:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe print".

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

one point: have you escaped all `\` correctly ?
another point: try Invoke-Command instead of Invoke-Expression

Comment: Yep everything was all good, see my edited question/answer.  Thank you for posting though.